# Normalizing rows of matrix, so that their norm is equal to 1 (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, normalization, norm

I have a following problem - I have a matrix `A` of size 16x22440.

What I need to do is to normalize each row of this matrix, so that the norm of each of them is equal to 1 (`for n=1:16 norm(A(n,:))==1`)

How can I achieve that in matlab?

Edit:
Each row in this matrix is a vector created of an 160x140 image and thus must be considered separately. The values need to be normalised to create an eigenfaces matrix.

Comment: Eucleadian norm is the case.

Comment: then my answer should be useful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your install of Matlab include the Neural Network Toolbox? If so, then try [`normr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/normr.html):

```
nA = normr(A);
```

Otherwise, [@Shai's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508504/1714410) is good except that it won't handle infinite or `NaN` inputs – it's much safer to check undefined norm cases afterwards:

```
nA = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,sqrt(sum(A.^2,2)));
nA(~isfinite(nA)) = 1; % Use 0 to match output of @Shai's solution, Matlab's norm()
```

Note that normalizing of a zero length (all zero components) or infinite length vector (one or more components `+Inf` or `-Inf`) or one with a `NaN` component is not really well-defined. The solution above returns all ones, just as does Matlab's `normr` function. Matlab's [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) function, however, exhibits different behavior. You may wish to specify a different behavior, e.g., a warning or an error, all zeros, NaNs, components scaled by the vector length, etc. This thread discusses the issue for zero-length vectors to some extent: [How do you normalize a zero vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722073/how-do-you-normalize-a-zero-vector).

Comment: Thank you, glad to find out about the easy way to do it!

Answer (score 6):

First, compute the norm (I assume Eucleadian norm here)

```
n = sqrt( sum( A.^2, 2 ) );
% patch to overcome rows with zero norm
n( n == 0 ) = 1;
nA = bsxfun( @rdivide, A, n ); % divide by norm
```

Comment: Well, after using your code the norms for each row are ~0, instead of 1: 
8.6903e-05;   

   1.3841e-04

   1.6891e-04

   2.0224e-04;   

   3.5168e-04;   

   4.0101e-04

   5.7108e-04;   

   6.3513e-04;   

   6.6574e-04;   

   8.1582e-04;   

   8.5704e-04;   

   8.7563e-04;   

    0.0010;   

    0.0012;   

    0.0015;   

    0.0017;

Comment: @Jacka forgot to take `sqrt` of norm. See if my fix works now.