# C++ Collision Detection causing objects to disappear

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-physics

I am currently working on some basic 2D RigidBody Physics and have run into an issue. I have a function that checks for collision between a Circle and a AABB but sometimes the Circle (in this case the player) will collide then disappear and if I print out the position when this happens I just set "nan".

```
bool Game::Physics::RigidBody2D::CircleAABB(RigidBody2D& body)
{
    sf::Vector2f diff =  m_Position - body.m_Position;

    sf::Vector2f halfExtents = sf::Vector2f(body.m_Size.x / 2.0f, body.m_Size.y / 2.0f);

    sf::Vector2f diffContrained = diff;

    if (diff.x > halfExtents.x)
    {
        diffContrained.x = halfExtents.x;
    }
    else if (diff.x < -halfExtents.x)
    {
        diffContrained.x = -halfExtents.x;
    }
    if (diff.y > halfExtents.y)
    {
        diffContrained.y = halfExtents.y;
    }
    else if (diff.y < -halfExtents.y)
    {
        diffContrained.y = -halfExtents.y;
    }
    sf::Vector2f colCheck = diff - diffContrained;
    sf::Vector2f VDirNorm = NormVector(colCheck);
    sf::Vector2f colToPlayer = NormVector(m_Position - (diffContrained + body.m_Position));
    float dist = getMagnitude(colCheck) - m_fRadius;
    //std::cout << dist << std::endl;
    if (dist < 0)
    {
        OnCollision((diffContrained + body.m_Position) - m_Position);
        m_Position += (VDirNorm * abs(dist));
        body.m_Position -= (VDirNorm * abs(dist))* (1.0f - body.m_fMass);

        return true; //Collision has happened
    }
    return false;
}
```

This happens randomly and with almost no clear reason although it seems to happen more often when the circle is moving fast but can happen as well when it is moving slowly or one or two times when it is not moving at all.

An added note is that I apply gravity to the Y velocity and on collision set the velocity of the coordinating axis to 0.

So my question is, is something clearly wrong here to those with more physics experience than me?

Note: Using SFML for drawing and Vector2 class physics code is all mine.

EDIT: The OnCollision function checks the side the collision so that objects that inherit can use this (e.g. check if the collision was below to trigger a "isGrounded" boolean). In the this case the player checks the side and then sets the velocity on that axis to 0 and also trigger a isGrounded boolean when it is below.

```
void Game::GamePlay::PlayerController::OnCollision(sf::Vector2f vDir)
{

if (abs(vDir.x) > abs(vDir.y))
    {
        if (vDir.x > 0.0f)
        {
            //std::cout << "Right" << std::endl;
            //Collision on the right
            m_Velocity.x = 0.0f;
        }
        if (vDir.x < 0.0f)
        {
            //std::cout << "Left" << std::endl;
            //Collision on the left
            m_Velocity.x = 0.0f;
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if (vDir.y > 0.0f)
        {
            //std::cout << "Below" << std::endl;
            //Collision below
            m_Velocity.y = 0.0f;
            if (!m_bCanJump && m_RecentlyCollidedNode != nullptr)
            {
                m_RecentlyCollidedNode->ys += 3.f;
            }
            m_bCanJump = true;
        }
        if (vDir.y < 0.0f)
        {
            //std::cout << "Above" << std::endl;
            //Collision above
            m_Velocity.y = 0.0f;

        }
    }
}
```

From debugging out velocity and position no real reason has come to the surface.

```
inline sf::Vector2f NormVector(sf::Vector2f vec)
{
    float mag = getMagnitude(vec);
    return vec / mag;
}
```

Solution:

```
if (colCheck.x == 0 && colCheck.y == 0)
{
    std::cout << "Zero Vector" << std::endl;
    float impulse = m_Velocity.x + m_Velocity.y;
    m_Velocity.x = 0;
    m_Velocity.y = 0;
    m_Velocity += NormVector(diff)*impulse;
}
else
{
    VDirNorm = NormVector(colCheck);
    dist = getMagnitude(colCheck) - m_fRadius;
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging and report back with what you find.

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mcve]. In particular, we need to know what `NormVector` does on a code-wise level, and also what `OnCollision` does. So far, those look like the most likely culprits.

Comment: Sorry! Will add more detail.

Comment: @Xirema Everything good now? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue I see is `NormVector` with a zero vector.  You'll divide by zero, generating NaNs in your returned vector.  This can happen in your existing code when `diff` and `diffContrained` are the same, so `colCheck` will be (0,0) causing `VDirNorm` to have NaNs in it, which will propagate into `m_position`.

Typically, a normalized zero length vector should stay a zero length vector (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722073/how-do-you-normalize-a-zero-vector)), but in this case, since you're using the normalized vector to offset your bodies after the collision, you'll need to add code to handle it in a reasonable fashion.

Comment: Oh wow, I am not entirely sure how I would go about fixing that but you are completely right, I will see what I can do and see if this was the issue! Thanks!

Comment: I'm inclined to argue that NaN's are a perfectly valid response to normalizing a Zero-Vector (though OP still needs to make code changes to avoid calling normalize on a Zero Vector in the first place) but based on [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722073/how-do-you-normalize-a-zero-vector), it sounds like the correct way to normalize a zero vector is to leave it unchanged. So I would probably add that to the answer.

Comment: After some small debugging you are completly correct, this happens when colCheck is 0,0. I tried keeping VDirNorm to 0,0 when this happens but the same issue happens. Fixing this might be hard! But thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Did it! 
Will add the result to the question!